# QGraphics View layout

Tags: qt, layout, qgraphicsview

Can somebody help me understand how the `QGraphicsView` works within a `QVBoxlayout`?

I inherit a class from `QWidget` and the following code works as expected when it gets displayed:

```
m_mainVBoxLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
this->setLayout(m_mainVBoxLayout);
QWidget *testWidget=new QWidget();
testWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
m_mainVBoxLayout->addWidget(testWidget);
QWidget *testWidget2=new QWidget();
testWidget2->setAutoFillBackground(true);
m_mainVBoxLayout->addWidget(testWidget2);
```

When I run it the screen is divided vertically and there are two shaded boxes for the test Widgets as expected.

But if I remove `testWidget2` code and replace it by:

```
QGraphicsView *view=new QGraphicsView();
m_mainVBoxLayout->addWidget(view);
```

The layout is messed up in that I don't see the shaded box for testWidget.
I even tried creating a scene and adding it to the view to no avail.
Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I need to learn how to read better (Qt Documentation)

You have to use the viewport() method of QGraphicsView to get the default QWidget associated with it.

m_mainVBoxLayout->addWidget(view->viewport());

fixes the problem.